# Solaris 11, How to map device to mount point?

Tags: solaris

```
Solaris 11,
iostat -xncz 5 
                       extended device statistics
        r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
    ....
    6.0   18.2  226.7  205.6  0.0  0.0    0.0    1.7   0   3 vdc206
    6.8   39.6  252.6  341.0  0.0  0.1    0.0    1.5   0   4 vdc207
    0.2   30.0    9.4  266.9  0.0  0.0    0.0    1.1   0   1 vdc208
    6.6   19.4  242.2  330.1  0.0  0.0    0.0    1.9   0   4 vdc209
    6.8   36.4  230.9  371.2  0.0  0.1    0.0    1.4   0   4 vdc210
    ....
```

the mounts like, df

```
    ...
    /S0T1          (ds/S0T1       ): 7815505 blocks  7815505 files
    /S0Q1          (ds/S0Q1       ): 9602502 blocks  9602502 files
   ...
```

I may want to know how these devices, vdc* mapped to the mounts, /S0*?

Answer (score 0):

These are ZFS datasets, correct?  If you run `zpool status ds`, you should see something like

```
  pool: ds
 state: ONLINE
  scan: ...

config:

        NAME       STATE      READ WRITE CKSUM
        ds         ONLINE        0     0     0
          vdc206   ONLINE        0     0     0
          vdc207   ONLINE        0     0     0
```

The exact structure will depend on the way the pool is constructed.  But I'm guessing that the devices are in a mirror or a RAIDZ array, or something similar, in which case there's no way to map the devices to the mountpoints.  This is the way ZFS is supposed to work: take a bunch of raw devices, abstract them away, and give you a single pseudo-device (in no Unix sense of the word) from which you can carve out filesystem namespace.